# How to assign a sequelize Model to typed property

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I explain i have this properties definition

```js
export interface CrudOpts {
  Model?: ModelCtor<Model>;
  only?: string[];
  except?: string[];
  nestedRelations?: boolean;
  basepath?: string;
}
```

when I use it in a decorator:

```js
export function crud(opts: CrudOpts): Function {
  return (target: any) => {
    Reflect.defineMetadata('crud', opts, target.prototype);
  }
}
```

and then here:

```js
@crud({Model: Runner})
export class RunnerController {
  
}
```

I get this error

```
src/controllers/runner.controller.ts(6,8): error TS2322: Type 'typeof Runner' is not assignable to type 'ModelCtor<Model<any, any>>'.
  Type 'typeof Runner' is not assignable to type 'typeof Model'.
    Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
      Type 'new (values?: RunnerCreateAttributes, options?: BuildOptions) => Runner' is not assignable to type 'abstract new <TModelAttributes extends {} = any, TCreationAttributes extends {} = TModelAttributes>(values?: TCreationAttributes, options?: BuildOptions) => Model<TModelAttributes, TCreationAttributes>'.
        Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
          Type 'TCreationAttributes' is not assignable to type 'RunnerCreateAttributes'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Optional<RunnerAttributes, "id">'.
              Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Omit<RunnerAttributes, "id">'.
                Type 'TCreationAttributes' is not assignable to type 'Omit<RunnerAttributes, "id">'.
                  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Omit<RunnerAttributes, "id">': email, avatar_url, firstname, lastname, and 14 more.
```

What I understand is that the Runner Model type can't be assigned to ModelCtor because of their type definitions but my question is how can I achieve this kind of thing to code cleanly with types ? does we have a type to assign models we defined to ?

here is my model definition:

```js
class Runner extends Model<RunnerAttributes, RunnerCreateAttributes> {
  public id!: number;
  public email!: string;
  public firstname!: string;
  public lastname!: string;
  public avatar_url!: string;
  public timeto_id!: string;
  public profile_type!: string;
  public gender!: string;
  public is_trial_registered!: boolean;
  public is_anonyme!: boolean;
  public birthdate!: string;
  public bib!: number;
  public sas!: string;
  public subscription_date!: string;
  public year_id!: number;
  public group_id!: number;
  public subgroup_id!: number;
  public subgroupcompany_id!: number;
  public roles!: string[]
}

Runner.init({
  id: {
    type: BIGINT,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  avatar_url: TEXT,
  email: {
    type: STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  firstname: STRING,
  lastname: STRING,
  timeto_id: {
    type: STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  profile_type: {
    type: STRING,
    allowNull: true,
    defaultValue: 'public'
  },
  gender: STRING,
  is_trial_registered: BOOLEAN,
  is_anonyme: BOOLEAN,
  birthdate: DATE,
  bib: INTEGER,
  sas: STRING,
  subscription_date: DATE,
  year_id: {
    type: INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  },
  group_id: INTEGER,
  subgroup_id: INTEGER,
  subgroupcompany_id: INTEGER,
  roles: {
    type: ARRAY(STRING)
  }
}, {
  timestamps: false,
  tableName: 'runner',
  sequelize
})

export {Runner};
```

thanks in advance